# Select rows where all values within group are NULL

Tags: sql, sqlite

How to:
Select rows where all rows within group are `NULL`. Below group is defined by `id`. I
wish to select rows where all values are `NULL`.

```
Id Var1
1  NULL
1  NULL    
1  NULL  
2  10
2  20
2  30
3  NULL
3  30
```

What I have tried:

```
select id
from table 
where all var1 is null
group by id
```

Desired result:

```
id var1
1  NULL
1  NULL    
1  NULL
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `having` instead of `where`.  It filters *after* aggregation:

```
select id
from table 
group by id
having max(var1) is null;
```

A similar method uses:

```
having count(var1) = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try with this query:

```
select id,Var1
from table1 as a
where not exists (select id
                  from table1 as b
                  where a.id=b.id and b.Var1 is not null)
```

The subquery get the id that have values not null, so you don get them in the main query